# IE ProxyEnable via registry not working WIN 10

Tags: powershell, proxy, windows-10, registry, internet-explorer-11

How weird is this?

When I enable proxy in Internet Explorer 11 using the registry method, I check my IP and it's not proxied. **I click on Internet Options > Lan Settings (nothing else) then my IP changes to the proxy IP**.

While the lan settigs window already has Proxy checkbox checked. I don't click "OK" or anything for the changes to take effect, Just by clicking LAN settings the changes take effect as they should. 
The same is true for Disabling the proxy.

> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet
>   Settings] "ProxyEnable"=dword:00000001

This code doesn't work either. It executes fine as RemoteSigned policy but makes no difference.

```
function refresh-system() {
    $signature = @'
[DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern bool InternetSetOption(IntPtr hInternet, int dwOption, IntPtr lpBuffer, int dwBufferLength);
'@

    $INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED   = 39
    $INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH            = 37
    $type = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $signature -Name wininet -Namespace pinvoke -PassThru
    $a = $type::InternetSetOption(0, $INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED, 0, 0)
    $b = $type::InternetSetOption(0, $INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH, 0, 0)
    return $a -and $b
}
```

- IE 11.1593
- Automatically detect settings = unchecked
- Cache disabled = via GPO
- Windows 10 LTSB 1607
- No domain = Local user/Workgroup

Comment: Funny. Exact same thing happening to me on a windows server 2016 box in AWS.

Comment: Yes, I am facing this exact same thing. Any repairs on this?

--- Happens to me on the Windows Server 2016 in Azure.

Comment: Ahh shoot, I solved this, completely forgot how. It was something which included wmic and netsh, so stry the default netsh commands, should work https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/microsoft-defender-atp/configure-proxy-internet 
Forget about the registry, if windows was monitoring every object in the registry 24/7 your pc wouldn't have time for you ;)