# IE force proxy enable/disable via registry

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, proxy, registry

I used to rely on the regedit working enable/disable the proxy via this reg entry :

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
"ProxyEnable"=dword:00000001
```

and last week I found it wasn't working unless I close/reopen the IE windows or open/close the IE internet options dialog - possibly due to windows 10 as mentioned here
[IE ProxyEnable via registry not working WIN 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45873492/ie-proxyenable-via-registry-not-working-win-10/47077839)

The same problem was answered here [IE Enable/Disable Proxy Settings via Registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21568502/ie-enable-disable-proxy-settings-via-registry/47070432)
using powershell but I'm looking for a vbs solution and not found one  :(

I've tried my best to do this without powershell (regedits from batch files, vbs etc) and whether I edit HKCU or HKU/sid, it doesn't work because IE doesn't read it in apparently until you close & reopen the windows or open/close the internet options dialog. Has anyone got this working in vbs or something?